# Check for spelling mistakes in folder names

Tags: windows-xp

Many programs are available to check for spelling mistakes or wrong grammar.

Is it possible to use spell checking on folder names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it quick and dirty using the command line. At the prompt browse to the root directory , then type

```
dir /b /s > output.txt
```

This will output a list of all the files and directories (and subdirectories) in the folder to output.txt. Then open output.txt in Word and use Word's spell checker.

Comment: Nice and simple. Word of caution, clean out your temp files first. I tried it and got a bucket load of irrelevant stuff. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply pull off a list of folder names into a text file and run a spell check on that file?

[This VB code snippet](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=7978) will list all folder names on a computer, at the moment it writes to the screen but piping the output to a text file should get you a full list. Then simply open that list in a word processor and run a spell check.